# Trouble retrieving Has Many using Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

When I try to get episodes back from a podcast I get `invalid association []`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Podcast struct {
    Id       int
    Title    string
    RssUrl   string `sql:"unique_index"`
    Url      string
    Episodes []Episode
}

type Episode struct {
    Id         int
    PodcastID  int `sql:"index"`
    Title      string
    Url        string `sql:"unique_index"`
    Downloaded bool
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "gorm.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db.LogMode(true)

    db.CreateTable(&Podcast{})
    db.CreateTable(&Episode{})

    podcast := Podcast{
      Title:    "My Podcast",
      RssUrl:   "http://example.com/feed/",
      Url:      "http://www.example.com",
      Episodes: []Episode{{Title: "Episode One Point Oh!", Url: "http://www.example.com/one-point-oh", Downloaded: false}},
    }

    var episodes []Episode
    db.Model(&podcast).Related(&episodes)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of GO and GORM are you using? I've tried on my machine and this is the log:

```
[2015-06-17 19:02:11]  [12.00ms]  CREATE TABLE "podcasts" ("id" integer,"title" varchar(255),"rss_url" varchar(255),"url" varchar(255) , PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
[2015-06-17 19:02:11]  [1.26ms]  CREATE TABLE "episodes" ("id" integer,"podcast_id" integer,"title" varchar(255),"url" varchar(255),"downloaded" bool , PRIMARY KEY ("id")) 
[2015-06-17 19:02:11]  [1.25ms]  SELECT  * FROM "episodes"  WHERE ("podcast_id" = '0')
```

Please note that because you didn't create the podcast variable, the podcast_id is 0 so the query does not make so much sense.

In order to create the podcast, simply add this code

```
db.NewRecord(podcast)
db.Create(&podcast)

var episodes []Episode
db.Model(&podcast).Related(&episodes)

log.Print(episodes)
```

Comment: My version of gorm was really out of date. I must have previously ran a go get on it and its been sitting there stale without me knowing. Could you give me a code example of how I should create the podcast variable? Thanks!

Comment: The above still searches podcast_id = 0 though?

Comment: No because the podcast id is populated by gorm after inserting ;)

Comment: (/home/gregf/code/go/src/github.com/gregf/gormtest/main.go:48)
[2015-06-17 15:28:58]  [0.55ms]  SELECT  * FROM "episodes"  WHERE ("podcast_id" = '0

Comment: on my machine everything is working, did you check if any error occurred? the Create method has a .Error property for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80854/discussion-between-alessio-and-gregf).